# NSUserDefaults value changes 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I save a bool value in NSUserDefaults like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"password"];
```

And then I synchronize defaults like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

But when my app enters background and then enters foreground my bool changes value to `YES`

Why does that happen ? I set my bool to `YES` only in one place in program, which is not managing when my app leaves/enters foreground.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code you're using to retrieve the value?

Comment: When are you setting the value, at what point in the app? When it is backgrounded?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you provided so the error will most likely not be in the lines you posted.

Comment: I use it in my classes like Password.m
I don't set any values in the AppDelegate

Comment: Check properly whereever you have setted NSUSerDefaults.I think when you entering in to app from background some code is executing.

Comment: Can you post your retrieving code?

Comment: You don't say how you are accessing your bool, when you say: "my bool changes value to YES".  Are you talking about a local variable named password that is a bool?

It might be that you are setting the value of the dictionary object with key "password" to NO, but you aren't really changing the variable in your app, possibly called "password" to NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform a simple test where you are saving your bool as

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:NO forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSLog(@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"password"]);
```

see what's the value..

Answer (score 1):

Your retrieval code should look something like this.

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"password"]) {
    //False
} else {
    //True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right key string (`@"password"` in your case) when you retrieve the boolean value. It is case sensitive.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"password"];
```

Do a text search in your whole project for this key and you will find the offending code.